# How to change the background color of list?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an array of data, in that I have three different types of status e.g. ok, pending and expired. While listing on this array I need to add different color for each status. How can I do that?

This is how I am listing the array:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="playlist in playlists" href="#/app/playlists/{{playlist.id}}">
    <img src="{{playlist.src}}" id="thumbnile">
    {{playlist.name}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Take a look at NgClass. It has different options to append classes based on a property/variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by ng-class conditional operator

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="playlist in playlists" href="#/app/playlists/{{playlist.id}}">
    <p ng-class="{ 'okay': 'status-okay', 'pending': 'status-pending', 'expired' : 'status-expired'}[playlist.status]">
      <img src="{{playlist.src}}" id="thumbnile">{{playlist.name}}
    </p>
</ion-item>
```

CSS

```
.status-okay {
    background-color: green;
}

.status-pending {
    backgroud-color: yellow;
}

.status-expired {
    backgroud-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use ng-class and give them different css classes.

```html
<p ng-class="{strike: deleted, bold: important, red: error}">Example</p>
```

You can read more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass